# MS Access, How to determine the command line parameters that the current instance of application has started with?

Tags: ms-access, command-line-arguments

I need VBA solution to get the command line parameters which has been fed to MS Access at the start up of the current instance of the application. e.g. if it has been started as Runtime and etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don’t believe you can get the full command line used to start Access. However, you can certainly add a /cmd option to the startup swtichs, and VBA "command()" will return these values.

thus:
The VBA function command() will return the values after the /cmd

Thus:

A typical startup command line would look like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"
"c:\MyCoolProgram\MyApp.accde" /runtime /cmd "Parm1" "Parm2"
```

The above would be all one line (with a space between). To grab the two passed parms, then

```
Debug.Print Split(Command(), " ")(0)
Debug.Print Split(Command(), " ")(1)
```

You can also test if the application was launched with /runtime switch, or that you using the runtime version with this:

```
If syscmd(acSysCmdRuntime) = true then
   ' runtime version
```

So you can specify and pass startup parameters with the /cmd startup swtich

Comment: Thanks for help! How the difference between MS-Access run time version and regular ms access which has started with command line /Runtime can be determined if the syscmd(acSysCmdRuntime) is true?

Comment: Actually the “whole” idea of the /runtime switch is to 100% emulate and make the full version of Access behave EXACTLY like the runtime. So if you are testing, or developing a runtime version, then this switch will force Access to behave just like the runtime. (and you cannot install both runtime and full edition on the same computer). If using runtime only edition, then runtime switch is not required. If you must test, then use createObject("Access.Application") as that is not supported in runtime edition.